# Rsync not overwriting files

Tags: rsync

1. I have 2 directories- `etc` and `oldroot/etc`
2. I want all the files in `etc` to match exactly as `oldroot/etc`
3. If there are any files in `etc` that are not in `oldroot/etc`, I want to preserve them as is

I have tried every variety of flags I can think of with rsync, but I cannot get the desired result.

```
# # A few of the simpler commands I have tried
# rsync -Ia oldroot/etc etc
# rsync -Iac oldroot/etc etc
# rsync -ac oldroot/etc etc
```

They complete without errors. When I do a diff on the directories (`diff -r oldroot/etc etc`), there remains several of the same files that exist in both directories and with different content. I've been working on this 2 days, and needless to say I am frustrated beyond belief.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rsync --… oldroot/etc etc` copies the source directory `etc` to a subdirectory of the destination directory, so a file `oldroot/etc/foo` ends up copied to `etc/etc/foo`. If you want to copy a directory to a directory of the same name, specify the parent of the target directory:

```
rsync -a oldroot/etc .
```

If you want to copy a directory onto another directory, tell rsync to copy the contents of the source directory into the target directory by appending a trailing slash to the source. (A trailing slash on the target makes no difference.)

```
rsync -a oldroot/etc/ etc
```

Comment: 100% correct. I discovered the directory `etc/etc` just as you stated